# How can I navigate to a URL using JavaScript through IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, url

How can I navigate to a URL using JavaScript through IE, I have tried most of the functions for JavaScript, and they doesn't work for IE.

```
window.location.href = ''; //doesn't work for IE
window.location = ''; //doesn't work for IE

window.open(""); //does work for IE but it opens it in a new tab and I don't want this
```

Please I need help with that.
Thank You.

EDIT!!!

```
window.location.href = ''; //works well for IE, the problem was that I was using jQuery to build my HTML and solved by: jQuery.mobile.navigate("url.html#subPg");
```

Comment: `window.location.href` is universal, what happens when you attempt to use it?

Comment: @AlexK. the URL changes, but it doesn't navigate, I'm using jQuery mobile though, building the whole website in a single HTML page and navigating through pages IDs

Comment: Ah, `jQuery.mobile.navigate(..)` ?

Comment: @AlexK. I guess you are my MAN !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this
 `self.location=”top.htm”;`

tested in IE6,IE7
All the methods below should work in actuality -

1,

```
window.location.href=”login.jsp?backurl=”+window.location.href;
```

2,

```
window.history.back(-1);
```

3,

```
window.navigate(”top.jsp”);
```

4,

```
self.location=”top.htm”;
```

5,

```
top.location=”error.jsp”;
```

Comment: same result as window.location.href="";

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<script language="javascript">
window.navigate("");
</script>
```

Or this :

```
<script language="JavaScript">
self.location="";
</script>
```

-Mohamed Shimran